# Want to use class as a get set property in another class in Python

Tags: c#, python, asp.net, python-3.x

I have two classes and i want to use the "Page" class as a part of "Records" class as a get set property i have idea to do in c# but beginner in python so don't know how to achieve this,i am sharing what i have done

In c# below i have written:

```
public class Records
    {
        public int num { get; set; }
        public Page paging { get; set; }//how to write this line in python
    }

    public class Page
    {
    public int pagenumber { get; set; }
    }
```

Above similar i want to achieve in python

```
class Records:

    num=10
    #paging=""

    # def __init__(self):
        # self.__num = num

    def get_x(self):
        return self.num

    def set_x(self, num):
        self.num = num

    # def get_x(self):
        # return self.paging

    # def set_x(self, paging):
        # self.paging = paging

class Page:


    pagenumber=3

    # def __init__(self,pagenumber):
        # self.__pagenumber = 1

    def get_x(self):
        return self.pagenumber

    def set_x(self, pagenumber):
        self.pagenumber = pagenumber
```

### Below how to use above classes

```
objRecords = Records()
print("RECORDS",objRecords.num)

objPage = Page()
print("PAGE NUMBER",objPage.pagenumber)
```

Comment: You are aware that your don't need to write getters and setters in Python? It is actually an anti-pattern. If you need special behaviour of attributes use a `property`. Also attributes starting with `__` have name mangeling and might be confusing for beginners.

Comment: @KlausD. i am learning python so i was just following basic as of c#.Please let me know the best way to achieve the mentioned c# code as in python will be helpful

Comment: @KlausD. any references how can i achieve this ???

Comment: There are some important differences between OOP in C# and Python. It might be good idea to some kind of tutorial or course on that.

Comment: You most likely also don't want all your `Page`s to have the same `pagenumber` but this is what you currently do by using a class variable. You might wanna read about class variables vs. instance variables. But I agree with the general sentiment of @KlausD., it's best to read through some tutorials first. Explaining python's concept of OOP is simply too broad.

Answer (score 0):

HI i achieve my above issue with below solution

```
class Records:

    #num=10

    def get_x(self):
        return self.num

    def set_x(self, num):
        self.num = num



class Page:

    #pagenumber=3


    def get_x(self):
        return self.pagenumber

    def set_x(self, pagenumber):
        self.pagenumber = pagenumber

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = Records()
    obj.pg=Page()
    obj.pg.set_x(8)

    result=obj.pg.get_x()
    print(result)
    #output:8
```